# Were the Mishnah and/or the Talmud translated into Greek or Latin?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, translation, mishna

Were the Mishnah and/or the Talmud ever translated into Greek or Latin in ancient times as the Bible was?

Comment: Presumably not, as all the debates between the Jews and the Christians required an apostate to translate the Talmud for them.

Comment: I suppose a better question would be to ask, whether the contemporaries of חז"ל knew anything about the Talmud. For example, here's something interesting from Augustine: https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/2136-augustine#anchor8